# Event broadcast between servers in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, ipc

I have several node servers running on AWS (but they might be running anywhere).

An admin user can trigger a database save on one server (via an Express endpoint) which will in turn require all servers to reload that particular record. So, a particular server needs to be able to trigger an event onto N other servers.

Since the node processes are potentially on different servers, I can't use a Unix socket. And since I don't know in advance how many servers there are, I assume I will need to have one specific server which will "orchestrate" all of the other ones (see: each server "registers" and "pushes" events to that particular server).

What is the easiest, simplest solution to achieve this? I am talking about minimal amount of code and moving parts.

Comment: Polling is an option but the changes need to happen immediately, which is a pain for me.

Comment: is it possible for each different server to have a web interface? if so.. maybe set that up

Comment: They are accessed via a balancer.

Comment: well you could set up local web servers on each of them, forward them through ngrok and have them communicate with secrets only the local servers know.. the only issue there is which ngrok url would be your servers by sending their ngrok urls to a web domain that u own and taking things from there.. **in short**: virtual-machines -(ngrok_urls)-> online_webserver -(each_url)-> virtual_machine_connects

Comment: Ouch... Not quite super-simple ugh